# OpenCV cannot connect to X server

Tags: python, opencv, xserver

I'm trying to use a face detecting app to test things out, but when I run the script I get an error `cannot connect to X server`. If I remove the `cv2.imshow("Output", image)` functin everything works fine. Any ideas how I could solve the problem? Here's the script I'm using:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
import os

def mask_image():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
        help="path to input image")
    ap.add_argument("-f", "--face", type=str,
        default="face_detector",
        help="path to face detector model directory")
    ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
        default="mask_detector.model",
        help="path to trained face mask detector model")
    ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence", type=float, default=0.5,
        help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    prototxtPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"], "deploy.prototxt"])
    weightsPath = os.path.sep.join([args["face"],
        "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"])
    net = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
    orig = image.copy()
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (300, 300),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            face = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)
            face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

            color = (0, 0, 255)
    
            cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mask_image()
```

Comment: What OS are you running on? Have you set your `DISPLAY` environment variable, try `echo $DISPLAY`. Can you run `xclock`?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. `echo $DISPLAY` gives me this output: `:1`. And yes, I can run `xclock` ok.

Comment: Weird! Are you running inside some Jupyter environment, or IDE?

Comment: No Jupyter, just VSCode + Conda.

Comment: Try to set DISPLAY to 0